# How to use different action in Command Column in Grid for Telerik MVC extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, telerik-grid

I am using Telerik MVC extension version 2012.1.419.340. I had a problem with Command Column in Grid. I will use the example code on Telerik website to explain my problem.

I have view like:

```
@model IEnumerable<Order>
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
    columns.Command(commands => commands
                .Custom("viewDetails")
                .Text("View Details")
                .DataRouteValues(route => route.Add(o => o.OrderID).RouteKey("orderID"))
                .Ajax(true)
                .Action("ViewDetails", "Grid"))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
            .Width(150);
})
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnComplete("onComplete"))
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_CustomCommand", "Grid"))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
```

)

and my Order model like

```
public class Order{
  public int OrderID {get;set;}

  public string ShipAddress {get ; set; }

  public bool CanEdit {get; set;}
}
```

I would like my Command Column to use different Action depending on CanEdit value. For example, if CanEdit  is false, using action

```
columns.Command(commands => commands
                .Custom("viewDetails")
                .Text("View Details")
                .DataRouteValues(route => route.Add(o => o.OrderID).RouteKey("orderID"))
                .Ajax(true)
                .Action("ViewDetails", "Grid"))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
```

if CanEdit  is true, using action

```
columns.Command(commands => commands
                .Custom("editDetails")
                .Text("Edit Details")
                .DataRouteValues(route => route.Add(o => o.OrderID).RouteKey("orderID"))
                .Ajax(true)
                .Action("EditDetails", "Grid"))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
```

Can you give me some idea how to implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue by using Template Column in the Grid. I found there is no way to change Text for command column on demand. Thanks